# Silverlight Animating Control in ListBox

Tags: silverlight

I've got a user control that I'm using as my DataTemplate for all the items in my ListBox.  There's an animation in said UserControl that's pretty simple - it just expands a certain ListBox, and it works.  The thing is, when I scroll, every Nth item ALSO has the ListBox expanded, where N depends on how big my browser is sized to (in other words, how many items the ListBox is holding at any one time.)

It seems as though new items getting loaded into the listbox as I scroll are tripping over this animation.  Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Can you post your code. It would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your outer ListBox contains only a few items then add this to its Xaml:-

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel />
    </ItesmPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

By default the ListBox uses a `VirtualizingStackPanel` which only contains concrete instances of `ListBoxItem` that are currently being displayed.  Items a generated as needed by a `ItemContainerGenerator` which will recycle existing items.  I suspect some in there the state of an `ListBoxItem` is not entirely cleared when re-used to display another item from the ItemsSource.

Comment: Ha - that results in *horrible* performance.  What I ended up doing was just saving the state of the animation in my ViewModel, then checking it when the control is loaded, and adjusting accordingly.  Not the cleanest code, but it works.  Thanks, as always.

Comment: @Adam: This solution is only for when there are "few items" in the list.  I would agree the other approach would be to place state in the ViewModel however I would disagree that this isn't the cleanest, I think it is.  I would only suggest it if you are already using a viewmodel, however the very purpose of a __view__ model is to maintain __view__ specific logic and state in a testable class separated from the visual presentation itself.